# Autoordering sections interface with react

Tags: reactjs

I have to implement such component in react:
[image: Few sections list]

Requirements:

- we can have any amount of sections,
- if a section is disabled (it can be dynamically not rendered) then order number (1., 2., 3.) needs to automatically adjust,
- we can have different children inside of every section

Proposed interfaces:

1.

```
<OrderedSections list={[
  {
    title="Some Title",
    children={SomeComponent}
  },
 // ... more sections here
]} />
```

2.

```
<OrderedSections>
 <OrderedSection title="Some Title">
  // Some content here
 <OrderedSection/>
 // ... more sections here
 // ... some other elements can be here also
<OrderedSections/>
```

I would prefer 2. interface but it is hard to spread information from children to the parent to manage ordering. Maybe do you have some cool way of doing it?

What are the pros and cons of those solutions, which should be chosen?